# How to add Object to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code like this:

```
$scope.role.object_access_right = {contact:1,group:1,image:1,text:1,email_template:1,email:1,channel:1,campaign:1,invoice:1,user:1,account:1,tenant:1,}
```

I have empty array here,

```
$scope.access = [];
```

How can I push the key to empty array to have result ?

```
 $scope.access = [contact,group,text ...]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$scope.access = Object.keys($scope.role.object_access_right);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: thanks and more question,I want to get value and use: $scope.access = Object.values($scope.role.object_access_right); but it not work for me ?